# Please check whether this SQL query is correct

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to update the data in a row of a table which by specific user ID. But I am receiving syntax error. Could anyone tell me what's the wrong in the syntax or I miss something ?

Result of an echo statement --->

> UPDATE activitymeter SET totaltimes = 4, tna_wd = 1, tnm_wd = 10,
>   tna_we = 10, tnm_we = 10, mvpa_wd = 2, mvpa_we = 5, week_diff = -3,
>   tailor_advice= Your weekday activity level is below the recommended
>   levels but it looks as though this is improved on a weekend. WHERE
>   user_id = 2227904 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'weekday activity level is below the recommended
>   levels but it looks as though th' at line 10

Comment: Could you paste the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: Is user_id an integer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the sql client will tell you what is wrong and SO is not a community driven SQL client

Comment: How does the UPDATE look when processed?

Comment: Hi this is the syntax error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Yes usr_id is an integer

Comment: You will find that if you add line breaks in your SQL string, your code will be easier to read - both on Stack Overflow and in your editor. It's worth checking too that you don't have SQL injection vulns here - switch to parameter binding if you can.

Comment: Can we see the full SQL string? You'll need to `echo` it out so you can paste it here (in the question please, not in the comments - that goes for your error messages too).

Comment: first of all I would suggest using prepared statement to prevent sql injection, as for the query itself I don't see any issues with it.

If any of your variables is an empty String though I suggest you put NULL values in them instead before trying to run this query

Comment: Hi, thanks I have all the variable have default Null Values except user_id which is a primary key for the table.But still i have the same error.

Comment: See my earlier comment: **Can we see the full SQL string?** Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I always use more complete syntax (include all back-ticks for table names, etc) like so:

```
$intotable = "UPDATE `activitymeter` SET `update_totaltimes` = '".$totalactivity."', `update_tna_wd` = '".$timeweekday."', `update_tnm_wd` = '".$totalweekday."', `update_tna_we` = '".$timeweekend."', `update_tnm_we` = '".$totalweekend."', `update_mvpa_wd` = '".$mvpaweekday."', `update_mvpa_we` = '".$mvpaweekend."', `update_week_diff` = '".$dayenddifference."', `update_tailor_advice` = '".$tailoradvice."', `timestamp_column` = '".$tsnow."' WHERE `user_id` = '".$userid."';";
```

Comment: What does *full syntax* mean?

Comment: Hi, I am receiving the error like this   "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''activitymeter' SET 'update_totaltimes' = '1', 'update_tna_wd' = '1', 'updat' at line 1"

Comment: Sorry: "full syntax" may not be the correct term - what I meant was I always take time to add all the back-ticks around the table names etc.

Comment: Sathish: maybe echo out the complete SQL statement and paste it here. Also, take the complete SQL and try and run it as a query in PHPMyAdmin (Or whatever you are using).

Comment: UPDATE activitymeter SET totaltimes = 4, tna_wd = 1, tnm_wd = 10, tna_we = 10, tnm_we = 10, mvpa_wd = 2, mvpa_we = 5, week_diff = -3, tailor_advice= Your weekday activity level is below the recommended levels but it looks as though this is improved on a weekend. WHERE user_id = 2227904 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'weekday activity level is below the recommended levels but it looks as though th' at line 10

Comment: @Sathish: I think your problem is the full-stop at the end of the string you are supplying as the value for `tailor_advice`:

To the best of my knowledge it is best practice to:

 + enclose the values in single quotes ' ' if they are strings (as opposed to integers
 + enclose your table name and field names in back-ticks ``
 + end you statement with a semi-colon ;

Answer (score 1):

From the above printed sql query, the type of `tailor_advice` field is may be text or varchar, so the value must put inside double quotes or single quotes.